# Files prevented from hotlinking still viewable from the site's source code

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I have some files and images i want not to be viewable or downloadable. 
So when i just enter and load the url, let's say "http://www.domain.com/dir/image.png" it gives me 403 message as expected.

But when i access this url from the source code from the page which loads that image, it displays the image. But that shouldn't be possible, right?

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you view source on that page the referring domain IS your domain. It's not possible to prevent that.

When you just enter it in the address bar from about:blank , the HTTP_REFERRER is nil.